# Suspect incorrect Google Analytics Codes used

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have come across the following GA codes used for my site, however i am not very sure if it is technically correct.

What i am trying to achieve is to send GA information to two accounts, **xx-samplega-1** and **xx-samplega-2**.

```
<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
     _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xx-samplega-1']);
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ruby/appt_step1_page']);

     _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xx-samplega-2']);
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ruby/appt_step1_page']);

    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.maxonline.com.sg', 'search']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'fastbrowsersearch.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.babylon.com', 'search']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.maxonline.com.sg', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.conduit.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.esnips.com', 'searchQurey']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.freecause.com', 'p']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.goo.ne.jp', 'MT']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.hp.my.aol.sg', 'query']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.hiyo.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.iminent.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.mywebsearch.com', 'searchfor']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.sweetim.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.winamp.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search-results.com', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'websearch.rakuten.co.jp', 'qt']);

     (function() {
       var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
       ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
     })();
</script>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?  Is it working, or not?

Comment: We had a performance test that sees 100k concurrent users, but GA reports only 50 users at the most. I think this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with your analytics code:

1. If you want to send data to more than one account, you should give one of them a name (`t2` in the code below)
2. The `_addOrganic` commands should be before `_trackPageview` -- you'll also have to duplicate them for the `t2` tracker.

Something like:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xx-samplega-1']);
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'search.maxonline.com.sg', 'search']);
...
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'websearch.rakuten.co.jp', 'qt']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ruby/appt_step1_page']);

_gaq.push(['t2._setAccount', 'xx-samplega-2']);
_gaq.push(['t2._addOrganic', 'search.maxonline.com.sg', 'search']);
...
_gaq.push(['t2._addOrganic', 'websearch.rakuten.co.jp', 'qt']);
_gaq.push(['t2._trackPageview', '/ruby/appt_step1_page']);
```